# Finding shortest regex match in HTML

Tags: html, regex

I would like to match the last column in the first row from the following HTML:
 (this is just an example)

```
<tr> <td> ABC </td> <td> DEF </td> <td> ABC </td> </tr> 
<tr> <td> GHI </td> <td> JKL </td> <td> GHI </td> </tr>
```

So what I want to match is: `<td> ABC </td> </tr>`

I tried toying around with regex101.com but I just can't find a proper way to match the last `<td>` from the first row only.

What I got so far is the following regex: `(<td>).*?(<\/tr>)` which matches

`<td> ABC </td> <td> DEF >/td> <td> ABC </td> </tr>` though.

Is there any way to match only the shortest string between `<td>` and `</tr>` ? (I found similar questions but can't figure out a solution to this one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be as precise as possible when writing your regexps.

```
(<td>)[^\<\>]*(<\/td>)\s*(<\/tr>)
```

This assumes that the contents of the td tag does not contain html markup.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend your pattern with "start of string" (`^`) + "anything but `</tr>`" (`(?:.(?!<\/tr>))*`) to ensure no `</tr>` appears before your pattern (and therefore your match is the first one before `</tr>`). The original pattern should be captured with a group then:

```
^(?:.(?!<\/tr>))*((?:<td>).*?(?:<\/tr>))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/enGASL/1

Answer (score 0):

I would use this to match the required text into a group:

```
.*(<td>.+<\/td>?.+<\/tr>)
```

[Here is the **Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qckr3A/1)

Answer (score 0):

Regex 1 is 11 characters,

> ```
> <td.{14}tr>
> ```

Regex 2 is 30 characters but it'll cover any amount of content,

> ```
> <td>\s*\w*?\s*<\/td>\s*<\/tr>
> ```

but the real problem is that you wanted only one match, while this regex like most others will match more than once when the string is a multi-line HTML fragment. The solution is simple:

> **No global flag** - Once a match is found it stops

### Demo

```js
/* Regex 1
|| Literal: <td
|| Any 14 char or space (no line terminators)
|| Literal: tr>
|| NO GLOBAL FLAG - Once a match is found it stops
*/
const rgx1 = /<td.{14}tr>/;
/* Regex 2
|| Literal: <td>
|| Zero or more spaces
|| Zero or more word characters lazily collect until 
|| Zero or more spaces
|| Literal: <\td>
|| Zero or more spaces
|| Literal: </tr>
*/
const rgx2 = /<td>\s*\w*?\s*<\/td>\s*<\/tr>/
const str = `<tr> <td> ABC </td> <td> DEF </td> <td> ABC </td> </tr> 
<tr> <td> GHI </td> <td> JKL </td> <td> GHI </td> </tr>`;

let res1 = str.match(rgx1);
let res2 = str.match(rgx2);
console.log('Result 1: ' + res1);
console.log('Result 2: ' + res2);
```

BTW, there's a typo in the string: `DEF >/td>` and `JKL >/td>`

Comment: Thank you! I edited the typo and that regex was only an example and isn't neccessarily 11 characters but I like the idea anyway.

Comment: @mri Your'e welcome. I've updated to include any amount of characters as content in the `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(
`<tr> <td> ABC </td> <td> DEF </td> <td> XCC </td> </tr> 
<tr> <td> GHI </td> <td> JKL </td> <td> GHI </td> </tr>`
.match(/\w+(?=[</> td]+r>)/)
)
```